# How can I best represent my 2D thrust problem as a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming, computer-games

While my question stems from game dev, the problem itself isn't as much about the game, but more about correctly representing my problem as a linear programming problem that I can solve with a linear programming library (alglib.net, in this case).

#### Problem description

I'm creating a prototype of a 2D space game. The spaceship has various thrusters on it. For each thruster I have a unit vector representing its orientation, a vector representing its offset from center of mass, and a unit-less value representing its maximum thrust capability.

For each thruster, I want to calculate a value from 0 to 1 that I will use to determine a force vector for each thruster, which I then sum with the game engine to determine the net effect of the forces: `thruster.orientation * max_force * scale_factor`.

#### Constraints

I also have some constraints for my linear programming problem. Based on two inputs: the desired translation of the space ship (a unit vector) and a value (tau) which represents the desired angular velocity change. My first constraint, which I am having no issue with yet, is that the sum of the cross products of each thruster's offset and orientation vectors, scaled by the max_force and the to-be-calculated scaling factor, must equal the desired tau value. The other constraint, which I am having trouble with, is how to maximize movement in the desired direction while ensuring that the resulting vector points the same direction as the desired movement vector?

#### What I have so far

The expression that I'm trying to maximize currently is:

```
x * thruster1.force + y * thruster2.force + z * thruster3.force ... etc.
```

for each thruster on the ship.

My constraints are:

```
x * thruster1.force * thruster1.cross_product + y * thruster2.force * thruster2.cross_product + z * thruster3.force * thruster3.cross_product ... etc.
```

```
desired_direction.x = x * thruster1.orientation.x * thruster1.force + y * thruster2.orientation.x * thruster2.force + thruster3.orientation.x * thruster3.force ... etc.
```

```
desired_direction.y = x * thruster1.orientation.y * thruster1.force + y * thruster2.orientation.y * thruster2.force + thruster3.orientation.y * thruster3.force ... etc.
```

I know these last two are wrong, but I can't figure out how to maximize the x and y components of the resulting vector of the summed forces *while also ensuring their normalized value is the same as the desired normalized direction*. The constraints for the x component and y component are fundamentally linked, but how do I represent that with my constraints? I want my spaceship to maximize movement in the desired direction.

I suspect my current representation is fundamentally flawed and I'm not approaching this from the right angle, but I'm a little stuck at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximize movement in the desired direction"?  Do you mean to maximize the increase in the velocity in that direction over a unit time?  Using code to represent equations makes it hard to read the equations, because they are so wide and one has to scroll left and right to read the equations.

Comment: I tried to communicate it as best I could. I don't have a mathematics background so I tried to make it as clear as I could, though the readability did suffer.

Comment: By "maximize movement in the desired direction" I suppose more clearly what I meant was want the resulting sum of forces to by a vector pointing in the same direction as the desired unit vector, but maximize the length of the resulting summed forces vector. Same normalized value, maximized length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ be a vector denoting the summed forces from the thrusters, and $d$ the desired direction.  Then you want to maximize the dot-product $s \cdot d$, subject to the constraint that $s \cdot d^\top = 0$, where $d^\top$ is a vector that is orthogonal to $d$.  This ensures that $s$ will point in the same direction as $d$, and will be as large as possible in that direction.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. Vector and matrix math is all new math to me, but based on my understanding I think this is what I'm looking for. I'm going to try implementing it.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you again for your help. I now have some additional quirks which I think are more a result additional constraints I didn't know I wanted until now, but that'll be for another question.